# Redirect to previous URL in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel-6

I am hitting one URL (127.0.0.1/test) as a guest in laravel 6. It will redirect me to the login page and after successful login again redirect to the home page. After login, I want to redirect to 127.0.0.1/test.

Answer (score 0):

Use return Redirect::intended();